# Mixed model with first and second levels nested, but crossed higher levels

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, nested-models

I'm having trouble figuring out the equation of a mixed model I'm trying to estimate. For beginning, I have data collected for several municipalities and banking institutions over the years. In the way my data was set, each banking institution and municipality in a year is an observation. Practically, I desire to study the impact of some macroeconomic variables at the variables at the municipality-banking-year level, deploying a basic linear growth model of my variable of interest (Y for simplicity). I'm struggling particularly with the formal structure of the model. For instance, I've thought about using the following code in SAS for estimating this relationship in the unconditional linear growth model.

```
proc mixed data=df method=ml noclprint covtest;
class municipality banking;
model Y=year /solution;
random  intercept year/ subject=municipality_banking;
random  intercept year/ subject=municipality_banking(municipality);
random  intercept year/ subject=municipality_banking(bank);
parms/pdata=covpe noiter;
ODS OUTPUT InfoCrit=Model_0;
run;
```

(I've coded municipality_banking appropriately and sorted the data by it, so I haven't declared it as a categorical variable, following the recomendations of [this paper](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/332-2012.pdf)) .

Moving forward, this paper describes in [Figure 2.d](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.3137) the data structure I'm looking at, except my level 1 is the combination municipality-bank-year, nested within a combination of municipality-bank, and then crossed between both municipality and banking institution, as neither bank nor municipality are nested within each other.  So, my questions are the following:

1. Is this modelling correct? If so, how would one go to allowing this data design in the modelling?
2. Is my syntax in SAS correct for this problem?
3. In mathematical terms, how would I write the effects of the second level in terms of the higher crossed levels? For instance, would I have  two equations determing the intercept in the municipality-banking level (2nd level)  or would I incorporate two errors terms in this equation level (one for municipality, the other for banking)?

I'd appreciate any help!